# Problema a la hora de incluir JavaMail en el Netbean

Tags: java, netbeans, spring

Descargue la librería JavaMail y la incluí en mi proyecto primero creándola en el  Netbeans y despues adicionando la al proyecto pero cuando voy a crear la función de envió de correo no me reconoce algunas librerias.
Esta son las que me reconoce el Netbeans:

```
 import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
 import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
 import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;
```

Y estas son las que no:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

Cuando reviso mail no existe dentro de javax.
Me parecía que estaba incluyendo mal la libreria al proyecto pero hice una busqueda de como es que se hace y al parecer lo estaba haciendo bien.

Comment: ¿De qué forma has agregado la libreria a tu proyecto?

Comment: ¿Descargaste la librería desde aquí: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release? ¿Qué archivo descargaste?

Comment: ¿tienes pom.xml en tu proyecto ?

Comment: Al final parece que el problema era del javamail que descargue. @A.Cedano pon tu comentario como respuesta para darte los puntos ya que tu comentario fue el que me ayudo.

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A veces tenemos problemas porque no estamos incluyendo los archivos correctos en nuestra librería.

En el caso de JavaMail ha habido cambios recientes, como indica [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) al respecto:

> The open source JavaMail project has moved to java.net, where you can
>   download the latest release binaries, sample code, source code, etc.
>   The source code for the JavaMail API Reference Implementation is also
>   available in the Mercurial repository at the JavaMail project on
>   java.net.
>
> ---
>
> El proyecto JavaMail ha sido movido a java.net, donde usted puede descargar los últimos binarios ofrecidos, código de ejemplo, código fuente, etc. El código fuente para la Implementación de Referencia de la API de JavaMail también está disponible en el repositorio de Mercurial en el proyecto de JavaMail en la página web de java.net.

Esto significa que en la actualidad, **las librerías actualizadas para que JavaMail funcione sin problemas se encuentran [en la página de Java.net dedicada al proyecto JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release)**. Si descargas las librerías desde allí y las agregas a tu proyecto no deberías tener ningún problema.