# ¿Por qué razón una aplicación Java no me envía correo en algunas PCs?

Tags: java, email

Por favor si me pudieran indicar las posibles causas de por qué en algunas PC no puedo enviar correos desde una aplicación Java, mientras que en otras sí. Si el código expuesto no tiene error. ¿Creen que la causa puede estar en alguna configuración de Windows o en otra posible causa?

De antemano muchas gracias.

El código que estoy utilizando y que me funciona perfecto en la mayoría de maquinas que utilizan la aplicación es el siguiente:

```
public static void enviarinformecorreo(String asunto, String direccion1, String adjunto1, String nombreadjunto1, String cuerpo) {
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put ("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "correo@gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                  return new PasswordAuthentication("correo@gmail.com", "contraseña");
                              }       
                          });

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("correo@gmail.com"));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,new 
        InternetAddress[] {new InternetAddress(direccion1)}); 
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        MimeMultipart multiParte = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
        adjunto.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(adjunto1)));
        adjunto.setFileName(nombreadjunto1);
        multiParte.addBodyPart(adjunto);


        BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
        texto.setContent(cuerpo, "text/html");
        multiParte.addBodyPart(texto);
        message.setContent (multiParte);

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect("correo@gmail.com", "contraseña");
        t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        t.close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
  `    `func.mensaje(e.getMessage()+"--"+e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha habido cambios con respecto a JavaMail, revisa que tienes tus librerías al día, comenta el error que estás teniendo. Te recomiendo que [leas esto](https://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/)   y también la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60003/29967)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tengo la librería de JavaMail mas reciente y no me genera ningún error el programa, simplemente se realiza el proceso de envío del correo sin errores y en el destino llega el correo.

Comment: Puede que en algunos equipos esté llegando a la carpeta spam o algo así.

Comment: Voy a verificar ese punto y lo comentaré. Gracias

Comment: ¿De casualidad has revisado si se imprime algo en el stacktrace de excepción en los equipos donde ejecutaste el código y no se envió el correo?

Comment: Podría deberse al firewall de Windows o del antivirus, que podrían estar bloqueando los puertos que se están utilizando para el envió de correo o otra aplicación este utilizando esos puertos. También verifica que tengan acceso a internet.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias.
El uso de correo en java, suponiendo que el código está correcto, puede dar problemas por diferentes causas. A mi en lo particular los problemas han debido a dos causas:

1. Si la señal de Internet es débil, es muy posible que no funcione correctamente el envío o recepción de correos, aunque el código no tenga errores.
2. Si la maquina que corre nuestra aplicación de correo esta dentro de una empresa que tiene su propia red interna y con su propias medidas de seguridad, también es muy posible que nuestra aplicación tampoco funcione correctamente.

Answer (score -1):

Yo tuve un problema similar, sucede que actualice el jdk de mi pc, y a partir de ahi no habia podido mi aplicaicon enviar correo, entonces desinstalar esa actualizacion y reinstalar la que me servia, la clave es que no actualice el jdk posiblemente esa sea la causa y quizas java mail no sea compatible