# Android studio PasswordAuthentication cannot be applied to (String, java.lang.String) JAVAMAIL

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola tengo un error con el correo y la contraseña quería saber que  podría hacer para que no me diga:

> PasswordAuthentication cannot be applied to (String,
>   java.lang.String)

Seguí este tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXl5CifFlM0

```
package com.example.email;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String correo;
    String contrasena;

    EditText mensaje;
    Button enviar;
    Session session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        correo="prueba@gmail.com";
        contrasena="";
        mensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
        enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                Properties propiedades = new Properties();

                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                try {

                    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedades, new Authenticator() {
                        @Override
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,contrasena);
                        }
                    });

                    if (session != null) {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correo));
                        message.setSubject("Primera Prueba JAVA Mail");
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("prueba@gmail.com"));
                        message.setContent(mensaje.getText().toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                        Transport.send(message);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [Según la doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/net/PasswordAuthentication.html), el segundo parámetro debe ser del tipo **`char []`** prueba así:  `return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,contrasena.toCharArray());`

Comment: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.net.Authenticator', required: 'javax.mail.Authenticator' less... 
Inspection info:
getDefaultInstance
(Properties,
javax.mail.Authenticator)
in Session cannot be applied
to
(Properties,
anonymous java.net.Authenticator)
 ahora me sale esto

Comment: Me parece que el parámetro de `Session` debe ser del tipo `javax.mail.Authenticator`, prueba a cambiar esa parte: **`session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedades, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {`**

Comment: El paquete que tienes que importar es este: **`import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;`** en lugar de `import java.net.Authenticator; import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;`  y luego la sesión la pones como ya indico en el comentario anterior. Y esto lo puedes dejar como estaba: `return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,contrasena);` Supongo que usas [la nueva API JavaMail](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60003/29967)

Comment: casting 'findViewById(R.id.mensaje)' to 'EditText' is redundant less... 
Inspection info: This inspection reports unnecessary cast expressions.  en el button tambien no me los reconoce ahora pero si funciono lo otro

Comment: Ese es ya otro tema. Dado que  ya lo declaraste como del tipo `EditText`, aquí puedes hacer sólo esto: `mensaje = findViewById(R.id.mensaje);` y aquí: `enviar = findViewById(R.id.enviar);`

Comment: muchas gracias!! me funciono pero tengo otro error es:The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. se pone lento al enviar ,te lo agradezco mucho por tenerme paciencia conmigo!

Comment: Ese es otro asunto muy diferente. Lo que dice es que la App está haciendo demasiado trabajo en el hilo principal. Eso ocurre por ejemplo cuando cierto código que debería ejecutarse en background se ejecuta en el hilo principal, pudiendo bloquear la app. Debes revisar, hacer `Profiler`y cosas así para ver dónde está el problema. De todos modos eso no se puede tratar en esta pregunta ni mucho menos en comentarios, requiere un análisis exhaustivo de tu app.

Answer (score 0):

En el código se ve claramente que estás usando los `import` equivocados:

```
import java.net.Authenticator; 
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
```

Para autenticación usando `JavaMail`, tienes que importar esto:

```
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
```

Y el parámetro de `session` tiene que ser del tipo: `javax.mail.Authenticator`

Otra cosa es que si ya declaraste estos miembros de la clase con su tipo:

```
EditText mensaje;
Button enviar;
```

No tienes que hacer el *cast*  más adelante:

```
mensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mensaje); 
enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
```

---

El código corregido quedaría entonces así:

```
package com.example.email;

import android.os.StrictMode; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Message; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { String correo; String contrasena;

    EditText mensaje;
    Button enviar;
    Session session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        correo="prueba@gmail.com"; 
        contrasena=""; 
        mensaje =  findViewById(R.id.mensaje); 
        enviar = findViewById(R.id.enviar);
        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                Properties propiedades = new Properties();
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                propiedades.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   

                try {
                    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(propiedades, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
                        @Override
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(correo,contrasena);
                        }
                    });

                    if (session != null) {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correo));
                        message.setSubject("Primera Prueba JAVA Mail");
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("prueba@gmail.com"));
                        message.setContent(mensaje.getText().toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                        Transport.send(message);    
                    }       
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```